# Aligning text in th tag in JSX

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to center the text in my th tag, and it is working fine in my example here: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/qNxZBV but if I view my code in the browser (Firefox), the text in my `<th>` tags is not centered. I am not sure if this has something to do with the browser. I have some basic styling:

```
th {
   border: 1px solid purple;
   width: 125px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

And then in my ReactJS component where I render the `table`:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Course #</th>
            <th>Course name</th>
            <th>Credit hours</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Seats available</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {details}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is probably a CSS issue. There may be some rule overriding yours. You need to find the rule, and write a stronger one. Do you know how to use firebug to inspect CSS?

Comment: I do get a line-through through text-align and padding when inspecting my code.

Comment: I resolved it by adding text-align: center !important; to my css.

Comment: That resolves it, but it is not a very good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find whatever CSS rule is overriding yours, then rewrite your rule to be more specific than the one you found. For example, you can change your selector to be:

```
html body table th {
   border: 1px solid purple;
   width: 125px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Have a look at how browsers decide which rules are the most relevant - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

As a last resort, you could add `!important` to `text-align` declaration. But that will make it harder to override the rule later on - https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure how to rewrite a rule to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a !important after your text align. This will give it a higher priority. For example :

```
table th {
         color: #000 !important;
}
```